# Checkbox changed event does not call event after return true from clientside

Tags: javascript, vb.net, checkbox

i have a checkbox and function for it

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ckbtest" runat="server" CssClass="Label" Text="Responsible Persons"
     AutoPostBack="true" OnClick="return foo()" />


function foo(){
                if (false) {
                  alert('some alert.');
                  return false;
                  }
                  else{
                  return true;
                  }
                }
```

when i click on checkbox and it returns true from the function but after that it is not going to the server side

i suppose to go to the serverside after return true from the function

server side method

```
Protected Sub ckbtest_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ckbtest.CheckedChanged

        Try
     some code
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming foo() is a java-script function . Your code needs to be

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ckbtest" runat="server" CssClass="Label" Text="Responsible Persons" OnClientClick="return foo()" />
```

The attribute **OnClick** fires Server side functions only and also the **AutoPostBack** property automatically initializes a post back to the server.

Comment: if i put OnClientClick then it will not execute my javascript function foo(),
it directly goes to the checkedchanged event of that checkbox which i define on server side

Comment: Do you want both functions to get fired. what about removing AutoPostBack. Can you be a little more clear on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i want to fire serverside function if my javascript function return true. or you can also say that if my javascript function went in to else part

Comment: Are you trying to fire the server side event only when the checkbox is checked. If thats the case `if (false)` is very wrong it will always execute the else part and return true.

Comment: yes so after else part excute i want to call the server side function thats it

Answer (score 0):

i simply do that code in javascript to call checkedchange event of the checkbox.
that is feasible solution for me.

```
__doPostBack('<%= ckbtest.ClientID %>', '');
```

otherwise one can use button click or call any server side function from j-query